# Sqoop import of oracle table query throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle, sqoop

I am using this query

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbs-dev-vm-3001.cisco.com:1585:WIILDEV \
 --username MUSERNAME\
 --password MPASSWORD \
 --query 'select US_WORKERS_COMPENSATION_CD from wfrapub.cwa_job where FISCAL_YEAR_WK_NUMBER in (select FISCAL_YEAR_WK_NUMBER from wfrapub.CWA_FISCAL_WEEK_TO_YEAR where FISCAL_QTW_FLAG='Y') WHERE  $CONDITIONS' \
 --split-by FISCAL_YEAR_WK_NUMBER \
 --hive-table WFRAPUB.CWA_JOB2  \
 --target-dir /tmp/cwa_job2256
```

and I get this error saying -

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
```

However, if I trim the query to

```
 --query 'select FISCAL_YEAR_WK_NUMBER from wfrapub.CWA_FISCAL_WEEK_TO_YEAR  WHERE  $CONDITIONS' \'
```

Then scoop import is working. Is it because of join which is not getting handled in Sqoop? The query works in Toad for sure. What can be the reason for this syntax error ?

Answer (score 2):

Your query, somewhat paraphrased, basically reads as follows:

```
SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE some_column IN (...subquery...) WHERE ...
```

The second `WHERE` is wrong.  Try the following instead,

```
SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE some_column IN (...subquery...) AND ...
```